# How to align links vertically on a navigation bar that works across all devices?

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am unable to align links vertically to the center of the navigation0 bar but the logo overlaps the content.

**Here's the HTML Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TEXT ABC</title>
  <!-- Import Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Import Bootstrap CSS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Import Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-6Jz9w4jK8vRZ7W5vL+0z4u8j1U6qzqZJnZvKwJ9zBvJrEJLJvO7Qj5f8yqJyjW3jFZ5zJfV4zX7b7Zo1qJfQ1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <!-- Import Main CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../components/images/Sample Logo.png" alt="main logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center list-unstyled" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="../components/videos/mainVideo_First.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    <h1 class="text-center">Text</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Import Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-1l9wzJQvK8rJ9zq7s6+J6QJxH3sJ1yKb1zJ4q7zQz2WdJ5zL1Qzj8Qg1zjg7qQ7ZiMv4L8tLj5JZrR5qUJ5Dzg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here's the CSS Code**:

```
/* Global Styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

/* Navbar Styles */
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 90px;
    background: rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.718);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
/*
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
*/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .text-center {
      font-size: 10px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: visible;
    }
  }
.navbar-brand img {
    max-height: 50px;
    scale: 4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .nav-item {
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }


/* Video Container Styles */
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.text-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(22, 212, 53, 0.5);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Navigation Links Styles 
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}*/

.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #16d435;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.list-unstyled {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Can someone please help me where I have made the mistake and how can I fix the issue for all devices?

I tried aligning the text to the center but nothing worked.

Screenshots:

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYvsf.png)

[browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS4bh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues I found:

1. You missed the Bootstrap CSS cdn link in the header (instead there is Bootstrap js cdn) --> It will enable your bootstrap classes to work
2. You need to remove the class `container-fluid` from the `navbar-brand` container ---> It will push the logo at the left and will allow space for the navbar links on the right.
3. From `.navbar-brand img` you need to remove `scale: 4` ---> It will shrink your logo and it will be perfectly fit on the left and your navbar links will be perfectly aligned too.

I have tested and after these adjustments you will get a well organized and aligned navbar.

2nd revision:

Had to add the nav toggler button for the smaller screen, adjusted the logo size and changed some of the non working cdn links with the corrected ones and also had to change the navbar height property and more. Maybe your codes still have some issue why it shows some error here if you try to run here but works fine on browser if you copy paste in an html. Here are the codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TEXT ABC</title>
  <!-- Import Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Import Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Import Font Awesome -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-6Jz9w4jK8vRZ7W5vL+0z4u8j1U6qzqZJnZvKwJ9zBvJrEJLJvO7Qj5f8yqJyjW3jFZ5zJfV4zX7b7Zo1qJfQ1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <!-- Import Main CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">

  <style>
    /* Global Styles */
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    /* Navbar Styles */
    .navbar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        min-height: 90px;
        background: rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.718);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        border-radius: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    /*
    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    */

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .text-center {
        font-size: 10px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible;
        }
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        max-height: 50px;
        /* scale: 4; */
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 24px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 575.98px) {
        .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .nav-item {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }


    /* Video Container Styles */
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .text-center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(22, 212, 53, 0.5);
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    /* Navigation Links Styles 
    .navbar-nav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .nav-item {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }*/

    .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-link:hover {
        color: #16d435;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .list-unstyled {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../components/images/Sample Logo.png" alt="main logo" width="30" height="24"></a>
    
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center list-unstyled" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="../components/videos/mainVideo_First.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
    <h1 class="text-center">Text</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Import Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out fix the issues! 

While viewing in the mobile view, the links are not visible, and the logo becomes comparatively smaller (I have added screenshots in my post above)

Comment: The answer is updated. You need to copy paste the whole codes in an html and then try it in a web browser. Because for some reason it shows error here from the beginning.